# Conditional WHERE clause to combine two queries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, conditional-statements, where-clause, clause

I have a large `SELECT INTO` statement in a T-SQL script and currently I have two separate `SELECT INTO`'s only differing by one `OR` condition in the `WHERE` clause. If my variable `@cycle_nbr = 1` I have it doing one `SELECT INTO`, if `@cycle_nbr = 0` I have it doing the other `SELECT INTO`.

I was wondering if there was a way to do this in one `SELECT INTO` with the `@cylce_nbr` condition in the `WHERE` itself.

Here is my `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE ((a.gl_indicator = '0' OR a.gl_indicator = '1') 
       AND (a.gl_ins_type = '1' OR a.gl_ins_type = '3' ) 
       AND rel_file_nbr is NULL 
       AND a.alpha_line NOT LIKE '%Z'
       AND mis_process_dt >= @start_dt 
       and acctg_cyc_ym  = @acctg_cyc) 
       OR (a.prem_sys_cd='T' AND acctg_cyc_ym  = @acctg_cyc )
```

I only want this last condition `OR (a.prem_sys_cd='T' AND acctg_cyc_ym  = @acctg_cyc )` in there if `@cycle_nbr = 1`. Can I put an `IF` in there somewhere to make this work? Or do I have to stick with the `IF(@cycle_nbr = 1) run this select ELSE run the other select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your variable in the OR statement, i.e.,

`OR (a.prem_sys_cd='T' AND acctg_cyc_ym = @acctg_cyc AND @cycle_nbr = 1)`

Comment: What if it were an AND clause I wanted conditionally? For instance, I only want `AND date > start` to be there if my variable `@num = 2`.  I understand how it works if it were an OR clause, but I'm not sure it would work the same with an AND.